# Visual Studio 2013 SSDT Project Configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

How using SSDT can I set up different database configurations for the different configurations specified in my solution (e.g. DEBUG, RELEASE etc)?

In the VS2010 database project I used to be able to set up different connection strings, SQL command variables and deployment configurations dependant on which configuration I had selected. I was then able to right click on my solution and click "Deploy" which would deploy all of the databases in my solution to their target actual database services.

This was very useful during development when in DEBUG configuration I would tend to set the options to...

- Deploy to localhost\instancename
- Drop the current database(s) and re-create

.. and then in release mode I could create an upgrade script to run on a test database before go live.

As I have multiple databases in my project the ability to deploy all of them in one go was very useful, however these options seem to have been replaced in SSDT with a publish option where I don't seem to get settings per configuration mode or the ability to deploy everything at once. Additionally, there seems to be no way to specify SQL command variables per configuration.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution or work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

An workaround would be to create different publish profiles - from Publish window, after configuring the target database etc., "Save Profile As" `[database name].debug.publish.xml, [database name].test.publish.xml`...

If you want to deploy all databases at once, use a batch script to deploy. 
Let's say, for the test environment the command for each database would be:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile<path>\<database name>.dacpac /Profile<path>\<database name>.test.publish.xml`